# C++ Builder DBGrid export to Excel in xlsx file

Tags: c++, excel, delphi, c++builder

Before, I always used TXLSWorkbook and SaveDialog to export excel(.xls) from DBGrid.

However, now the exported data is too big, .xls file can't fill with all data.

I tried to export .xlsx file ,but TXLSWorkbook didn't seem to support .xlsx file.

When I open the .xlsx file , the error message said the file is broken.

Did I miss something or I have to find another way to export .xlsx file?

Here's my code. Thanks for watching.

```
TXLSWorkbook *WorkBook;
IXLSWorksheet *WorkSheet;
IXLSRange *Cells;
int Row;
TDateTime dt=Now();
String date = dt;

date = FormatDateTime("yyyymmdd",date);
FileName = date+".xls";
WorkBook = new TXLSWorkbook();

WorkSheet = WorkBook->Sheets->Add();

Cells = WorkSheet->Cells;
.
.
.
(input item to Cells...)
.
.
.
SaveDialog1->FileName = FileName;
if( SaveDialog1->Execute() == true ) {

    WorkBook->SaveAs(SaveDialog1->FileName);

}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use TDataset. You can save directly as Excel files via ADO. How to set the connectionstring look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like posting an answer which is a recommendation to use another 3rd-party library, but in this case it is perhaps appropriate.

See:  http://www.scalabium.com/sme/

This is a library which can export database data from Delphi apps to a wide variety of formats, including Excel file formats.  It does not use COM, so is not subject to limitations imposed by Excel's COM implementation, though I am not sure whether TXLSWorkBook uses COM.  AFAIK, SMExport writes directly to an Excel-format file.

There is a trial version available, iirc.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing!

Comment: But can we export to xlsx file without third-party source?

Comment: If you know how to write your own code to write your data to an xlsx-format file, then sure.  I think MS have published the specification.